# Why my derived table (subquery) can't have an alias

Tags: sql

Sorry for this weird question.

I know that sql has a rule which is "Every derived table must have its own alias." For example:
this is wrong:

```sql
SELECT ID FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM IDs));
```

and it should be:

```sql
SELECT ID FROM 
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM IDs) 
AS alias) AS anotherAlias;
```

but my code the `as alias` is wrong:

```sql
SELECT ID FROM tableA
WHERE ID NOT IN
(SELECT ID FROM tableB) AS alias;
```

Comment: you cannot put alias when using operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table alias is only needed for a subquery in the `FROM` clause.  Such a subquery is sometimes called a *derived* table.  All derived tables need an alias -- in some (but not all) databases.

In the `SELECT` clause, a subquery can also take an alias -- but that is a column alias.

In your example, the subquery is not representing any result set or value, so an alias is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not using the subquery as a table, you're using it as a collection of values in an `IN` clause within a `WHERE` clause.

Your first example has the subquery in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the reason for the alias. If I write:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM x
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT *
FROM y
) ON x.id = ???
```

The query breaks down. I can't refer to any fields in my derived table. Obviously this version works:

```
SELECT x.*
    , y.*
FROM x
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT *
FROM y
) y ON x.id = y.id
```

In the above, I need to alias y so that I can refer to fields in that derived table.

However, the following query does work without an alias as you mention:

```
SELECT *
FROM x
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM y)
```

So why does that query work? Well, we don't need the field names of anything in the sub-query. We are just referencing it as a list.

That's why if I write:

```
SELECT *
FROM x
WHERE id IN (SELECT id, id2 FROM y)
```

I see an error related to too many fields coming from the sub-query. We can only have one.

Does that help?